# How Do I know what V(ds) will be?

Tags: mosfet

I am trying to understand how to use a MOSFET as a switch. I want to use a microcontroller to control a load using an [AOI508 MOSFET](https://aosmd.com/res/data_sheets/AOI508.pdf) as in this schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2BbUB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now, if this were using a mechanical switch instead of a MOSFET, we could determine the current that would flow through the load using `I=V/R`: `I=12/1k=12mA`. However, the datasheet for my MOSFET shows that, depending on V<sub>GS</sub> and I<sub>D</sub>, there will be a voltage drop across drain-source:

[image: Vds vs Id graph]

So, the true current through the load would be given by I<sub>load</sub>=(12-V<sub>DS</sub>)/R<sub>load</sub>. But in order to calculate this we need to know what V<sub>DS</sub> is, which depends on I<sub>D</sub>, which depends on V<sub>load</sub>, which recursively depends on V<sub>DS</sub>. Obviously I'm missing something in my understanding but I have no clue what.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose we plotted what Vds will be, as a function of Id:

[image: Drain curve with load line]

When Id is 0, Vds is 5V.  When Id is 60A, Vds is 0.  This would be a 5V supply and 5/60 = 82mΩ resistor.

Note that, for any given point between min and max, Id or Vds depends steeply upon Vgs; and we don't really know Vgs, because it's relative to Vgs(th) which has a parameter spread.  We also need to respect device power dissipation or temperature ratings.

For saturated switching operation, you want to be as far left as possible when "on", so simply applying some reasonably high Vgs will do.  These are documented in the Vgs(on) for Rds(on) parameters, and Rds(on) vs. Vgs or Id graphs.  Pay attention to the min/max values, so you can be sure it operates as intended despite that parameter spread.

This transistor is rather overrated for a 12mA load, but I'm guessing that's just a placeholder, not a real load.

Comment: 1) Where do you get the red line from - it seems like it's drawn completely arbitrarily, is is not? 2) `When Id is 0, Vds is 5V. When Id is 60A, Vds is 0` - huh? where does that come from?

Comment: *"This would be a 5V supply and 5/60 = 82mΩ resistor."*

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Suppose V1 = 5V and Load = 82mΩ. What would Vds be while varying Id? Plot them.

Comment: Ah I see. I understand that much, but what I'm confused about is how can I "vary Id" if the current through the circuit depends on the voltage drop across the load, which depends on the supply voltage minus the Vds drop?

Comment: If only there were some active element, connected to the resistor, that could draw variable current, in response to a control voltage... :)

Comment: Ha, right. But in order for Ohm's law to remain true, the only way the mosfet can vary the current would be by changing the voltage drop across the resistor. So how can we control the current if the Vds voltage drop is constantly changing as we are changing Id? It seems like that would cause an infinite feedback loop.

Comment: i.e. if Vds changes depending on Id, how do we know how much voltage will drop across the load in order to calculate Id in the first place?

Comment: It's a system of equations: reduce it by substitution (or whatever) to find the equilibrium point.

Comment: Okay thanks. So what equations should I use? The datasheet only has a graph, it doesn't give a specific formula.

Comment: A compact closed-form formula relating Vds, Vgs and Id doesn't really exist, but wouldn't it be handy if such a relationship could be solved graphically?

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate the help :) Is my understanding here correct? At a given Vgs, the mosfet is only able to conduct a certain maximum amount of current. If we try to draw more current, the Vds drop will increase in order to decrease the current back under the maximum for that Vgs?

Comment: Operation traces along of the black curves, for fixed Vgs. They don't really show a maximum in the plotted range, but to the extent that it's not going to go beyond say +V, yeah, that's right.